# Rails Rake Task Not Seeing Model When Using NameSpacing for model relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, ruby-on-rails-6.1

`rails 6.1.4` `ruby 3.1.1`

I have a sub-directory in my app: `living_muay_thai`  I had a couple problems with my app because I was using the namespacing like so: `LivingMuayThai::Student` in the models.  With some help here on StackOverflow I have those issues resolve.  But I have another one with a similar issue that I need help on.  I can't find any help via tutorials and Google, so I'm asking here again.

I have a rake task to pre-fill a table with data. It runs fine on my local machine, but not when I push it up to Herokku.

I tried using the shorter model names (`Level, Requirement, LevelRequirement`, but they did not work. Then I thought it might be that the rake task is not in the `app/` directory. I tried to `require` the models, but that did not work.  I'm stuck.

My rake file:

```
namespace :living_muay_thai do
    
    desc "create level requirements records"
    task :level_requirements_upload => :environment do

        @reqs.each_line do |line|
          parts = line.split(",")
            parts[0].strip!
            parts[1].strip!

            req=LivingMuayThai::Requirement.create(:requirement_name => parts[1])

        # we have levels in the db, so add the level requirement here
        level=LivingMuayThai::Level.where(:level_name => parts[0]).first

        if level.present?
            lr=LivingMuayThai::LevelRequirement.create(:level_id => level.id, :requirement_id => req.id)
        end 

        end # reqs.each
    end # task
end
```

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "living_muay_thai_level_requirements" does not exist`

My models for this are in the `living_muay_thai/` directory.  I've changed them to use modules as instructed in another thread. That cleared up other problems, but then this one popped up.

Models:

```
# level

module LivingMuayThai
    class Level < ApplicationRecord

        has_many :student_levels
        has_many :students, through: :student_levels

        validates :color, presence: true
        validates :level_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

        has_many :level_requirements
        has_many :requirements, through: :level_requirements
    end 
end



# requirement

module LivingMuayThai
    class Requirement < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :level_requirements
        has_many :levels, through: :level_requirements
        
        has_many :requirement_techniques
        has_many :techniques, through: :requirement_techniques
    end
end



#level_requirement

module LivingMuayThai
  class LevelRequirement < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :level, class_name: 'Level', foreign_key: :level_id
    belongs_to :requirement, class_name: 'Requirement', foreign_key: :requirement_id

    validates_uniqueness_of :level_id,  scope: :requirement_id 
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help and insights.

Comment: Your database on heroku does not seem to be set up properly. What database config do you use?

Comment: Are the migrations up to date on your Heroku application?

Answer (score 0):

I have this working on Heroku now.  @max replied to me in a similar thread here on Heroku: [Heroku Rake Does Not See Namedspaced Model In Rake Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77119012/heroku-rake-does-not-see-namedspaced-model-in-rake-task?noredirect=1#comment135966864_77119012)

He noticed the foreign keys on my joins tables were `integer` and not `bigint`, and he mentioned that Posgres might have a hissy-fit over these.  I went through and created update migrations on all my joins tables to change these keys to `bigints`.

I ran the migrations on Heroku and ran the rake task. It worked great. My guess is Posgres is happy now.

```
# Example of change migration:

class ChangeIdsInLevelRequirements < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change 
    change_column :living_muay_thai_level_requirements, :level_id, :bigint
    change_column :living_muay_thai_level_requirements, :requirement_id, :bigint    
  end
end
```